# Converting internal blu ray drive to external drive

Tags: usb, sata, blu-ray

So I have a LG Slim Blu-Ray Combo Drive - SATA CT40N that I'm trying to make work with usb. I have a SATA to usb 3 converter that I plugged into my surface pro 3. Drive seems to get sufficient power as I can open it, put a disk in, and I can hear the disk spinning. Problem is windows won't detect it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is, in fact, insufficient power. Classic symptoms.

However, you may want to disable *"USB selective suspend setting"* - known to be a pain in situations like this. If it doesn't work get an external USB case for DVD that comes with extra usb-to-pin cable delivering extra power to the drive.

Like this:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-Slimline-Optical-Drive-Enclosure/dp/B003GSCS2G

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll look into this. Just out of curiosity, do you know the power required for this kind of drive?

Comment: It should say so on the label on the drive. usually it's 1.2 - 1.5 A.